# How to get results of "NOT LIKE" via doctrine2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to get the number of results where roles are not `ROLE_ADMIN_USER`. To do that I wrote following function in doctrine 2. But its not filtering the results. Any idea what it should be like?

```
public function getApprovedUserSearchNumber($searchQuery)
{
    return $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->select('COUNT(u)')
        ->from('AppBundle:User', 'u')
        ->andwhere('u.username LIKE :query ')
        ->andwhere('u.roles !LIKE :role ')
        ->setParameter('query', '%' . $searchQuery . '%')
        ->setParameter('role','%ROLE_ADMIN_USER%')
        ->andwhere("u.adminApproved= 'Yes'")
        ->getQuery()
        ->getSingleScalarResult();
}
```

Comment: You probably don't want to do this with `LIKE '%keyword%'`. That means to search for everything with "keyword" in it. So querying username "%foo%" will indeed match "foo", but also "barfoobar". Also searching for "%ROLE_ADMIN_USER%" will also match "ROLE_ADMIN_USER_LIMITED" for example. You should use the equal operator `=` and set the parameters without any `%` characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use **`NOT LIKE`**

```
public function getApprovedUserSearchNumber($searchQuery)
    {
        return $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->select('COUNT(u)')
            ->from('AppBundle:User', 'u')
            ->andwhere('u.username LIKE :query ')
            ->andwhere('u.roles NOT LIKE :role ')
            ->setParameter('query', '%' . $searchQuery . '%')
            ->setParameter('role','%ROLE_ADMIN_USER%')
            ->andwhere("u.adminApproved= 'Yes'")
            ->getQuery()
            ->getSingleScalarResult();
    }
```